# What does this regex mean

Tags: c#, regex

What I really need to know is :

1. What does `(?(` mean ?
2. What does `?:` mean ?

The regex I am trying to figure out is :

(notice the above mentioned symbols in the following regex)

```
(?(?=and )(and )|(blah))(?:[1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Have a look at this [Regex cheat-sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) as a starting point

Comment: Yes I am. Yes I am. Try out this string in c# it will accept it.

Comment: Just a reminder for the future: Add a comment above any regex within the code (maybe with an example) to avoid such problems in the future. RegEx are tend to be write-only code which is hard to read if you don't do this stuff on a daily base.

Comment: @Oliver as the regex was not mine and I was supposed to understand and make changes in it, I had to post it. Also, I am not used to do it on daily basis.

Comment: @harshit: But please add your understanding as a comment to the regex code so the next programmer has not to search on the web for an explanation.

Comment: @Oliver taking a note of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?(?=and )(and )|(blah))` pattern is used like if-then-else like  `(?(expression)yes|no)`
i.e `and` would be matched if `and` is there else `blah` would be matched

`(?:)` is a non capturing group.So it would not be included in the group or be used as back-reference \1

So,

```
(?(?=and )(and )|(blah))(?:[1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9]
```

would match

```
and 1900
blah2000
and 2012
blah2013
```

**NOTE**(it's all about the groups)

The samething can be achievend with this regex 
`(and |blah)(?:[1][9]|[2][0])[0-9][0-9]`.
The only thing in which these regex differ is the number of groups formed.

So my regex would form 1 group which would contain either `and` or `blah`

Your regex would form no groups.It will form a group only if it matches `blah`..

Comment: can you please explain in plain english? I mean why are there two ands? I have been reading the link given in other answer. I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick reference to some patterns:

```
.   Any character except newline.
\.  A period (and so on for \*, \(, \\, etc.)
^   The start of the string.
$   The end of the string.
\d,\w,\s    A digit, word character [A-Za-z0-9_], or whitespace.
\D,\W,\S    Anything except a digit, word character, or whitespace.
[abc]   Character a, b, or c.
[a-z]   a through z.
[^abc]  Any character except a, b, or c.
aa|bb   Either aa or bb.
?   Zero or one of the preceding element.
*   Zero or more of the preceding element.
+   One or more of the preceding element.
{n} Exactly n of the preceding element.
{n,}    n or more of the preceding element.
{m,n}   Between m and n of the preceding element.
??,*?,+?,
{n}?, etc.  Same as above, but as few as possible.
(expr)  Capture expr for use with \1, etc.
(?:expr)    Non-capturing group.
(?=expr)    Followed by expr.
(?!expr)    Not followed by expr.
```

The expression `(?(?=and )(and )|(blah))` is an `if-else` expression:)

You can test reqular expressions here: [Regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:...)
```

is a non-capturing [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). It works just like `(...)`, but it doesn't create a backreference (`\1` etc.) for later re-use.

```
(?(condition)true|else)
```

is a [conditional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) which tries to match `condition`; if that succeeds, it will then try to match `true`, if not, it will try to match `else`.

This is a rarely seen regex construct because there are not too many use cases for it. In your case,

```
(?(?=and )(and )|(blah))
```

could have been rewritten as

```
(and |blah)
```

Answer (score 0):

`?:` is a non-capturing group. 
`(?ifthen|else)` is used to construct if, then expression.

You can read more about these here.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html